# Need to disable F10 key's Frame Focus in swing applet

Tags: java, swing, keyevent, jmenubar

i am using <kbd>F10</kbd> as shortcut for update data into database.whenever i press <kbd>F10</kbd> Updates Works Fine but.my Focus Moved to Menu bar(the bar contains close,minimize,maximize) is there anyway to stop this?i know this is windows shortcut.is that possible to stop it?

Comment: Sure.  Launch the applet *free floating* using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to remove the `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` action from your `JMenuBar`. Just add this line into your code :

```
menuBar.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F10"), "none");
```

Where the `menuBar` is the reference for your `JMenuBar` component.

**EDIT :**

Indeed, in case you're not using `JMenuBar` the above solution does not work. An alternative solution is to create an empty action and use it to bind the `F10` key. (see [Key Bindings][1]).

Here is an example :

```
 //create an empty action which do nothing
Action emptyAction = new AbstractAction(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {   //do nothing here   }};

//bind F10 with the empty action
KeyStroke f10 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( "F10");
frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(f10, "F10");
frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("F10", emptyAction);
```

Where `frame` is your `JFrame` component.
[1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: i had already seen this from here http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18687.html                      reason i am asking again,i am not using JMenuBar.i am only using JFrame Form.then how can i use this code.anybody can help me to do this.

Comment: Sorry, haven't noticed that detail. Please see my edit.

Comment: i need to take an action while pressing f10.i insert records into database when press f10.after pressing f10 i set all text fields empty and locate my cursor to the first text field.at the same time i insert all data in to database.so what should i do?